# class with no constructor forces the use of a pointer type?

Tags: c++

I don't want to use pointers when I don't have to, but here's the problem: in the code below if I remove the asterisk and make `level` simply an `object`, and of course remove the line `level = new Level;` I get a runtime error, the reason being that `level` is then initialized on the first line, BEFORE `initD3D` and `init_pipeline` - the methods that set up the projection and view for use. You see the problem is that `level` uses these two things but when done first I get a `null` pointer exception.

Is this simply a circumstance where the answer is to use a pointer? I've had this problem before, basically it seems extremely vexing that when a class type accepts no arguments, you are essentially initializing it where you declare it.... or am I wrong about this last part?

```
Level* level;

D3DMATRIX* matProjection,* matView;

//called once
void Initialise(HWND hWnd)
{
initD3D(hWnd);
    init_pipeline();

level = new Level;
}
```

I'm coming from c# and in c#, you are simply declaring a name with the line `Level level`; arguments or not, you still have to initialize it at some point.

Comment: It's nothing to do with whether `Level` has a user-defined constructor, or whether its constructors take parameters. The issue is that globals are initialized before `main` is entered. You'd see exactly the same thing if you wrote `Level level(1,2,3);`, the corresponding constructor would be called before `initD3D` and `init_pipeline`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are correct that if you do:

```
Level level;
```

then `level` will be instantiated *at that point*.  That is because the above expression, which appears to be a global, isn't just a **declaration**, but also a **definition**.

If this is causing you problems because `Level` is being instantiated before something else is being instantiated, then you have encountered a classic reason why globals suck.

You have attempted to resolve this by making `level` a pointer and then "initializing" it later.  Wjhat might suprise you is that `level` is still being instantiated at the same point.  The difference now is the **type** of `level`.  It's not a `Level` anymore; now its a pointer-to-`level`.  If you examine the value of `level` when your code enters `Initialize` you'll see that it has a value of NULL.

It has a value of NULL instead of a garbage value because globals are static initialized, which in the case here, means zero-initialized.

But this is all somewhat tangential to the real problem, which is that you are using globals in the first place.  If you need to instantiate objects in a specific order, then instantiate them in that order.  Don't use globals, and you may find that by doing that, you don't need to use pointers, either.

Comment: "it has a value -- but that value is garbage" - it's not garbage, because globals are zero-initialized.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this simply a circumstance where the answer is to use a pointer

Yea, basically.